# **argv contain a lot of characters than expected

Tags: c

First, I need to execute two commands with system(), for example, I receive an string and open this string with an text editor, like this:

```
$ ./myprogram string1
```

And the output should be a command like this:

```
$ vim string1
```

But, I cannot find a way to do this like this pseudo code:

```
system("vim %s",argv[1]); //Error:

test.c:23:3: error: too many arguments to function 'system'
   system("vim %s",argv[1]);
```

Therefore, my solution is store the argv[1] on a char array that already initialized with four characters, like this:

```
char command[strlen(argv[1])+4];
command[0] = 'v'; command [1] = 'i'; command[2] = 'm'; command[3] = ' ';
```

And assign the argv[1] to my new char array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]) ; i++)
    command[i+4] = argv[1][i];
```

And finally:

```
system(command);
```

But, if the arguments given to my program has less than 3 characters, its works fine, but if not, some weird characters that I do not expect appear in the output, like this:

```
./myprogramg 1234
```

And the output is:

```
$ vim 12348�M�
```

How can I solve this bug and why does this happen?

The full code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
 int main (int argc,char **argv) {

    char command[strlen(argv[1])+4];
    command[0] = 'v'; command [1] = 'i'; command[2] = 'm'; command[3] = ' ';

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]) ; i++)
        command[i+4] = argv[1][i];

        system(command);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char command[strlen(argv[1])+4];` is not legal in C++ as it does not support dynamic-size arrays on stack. garbage is printed because you forgot about terminating null character.

Comment: Strings must be 0-terminated, and you're not making sure that's the case.

Comment: It's in C, I tagged C++ because I guess that people who know C++, maybe know how to solve this.

Comment: I got it, how can I do this?

Comment: It is not legal in C either, unless you use something like C11 or whatever standard added support for VLA that later become optional.

Comment: Maybe people who know jQuery also happen to know what the problem is. But you should not tag `jquery` for pretty much the same reason as I am deleting `c++`.

Comment: @VTT: VLAs were added in C99, which is old enough at this point that I wouldn't feel bad calling VLAs part of C. C11 is when they backpedaled and made them optional (though most compilers support them).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Still, it is a good idea to never utilize new language features added after C89. Actually they shouldn't have touched core language features at all since then. Updating library a bit would be fine, but VLA is no good.

Comment: @VTT: In general, or under the plain `c` tag? In general, I understand avoiding VLAs (though in this particular case it's fairly innocuous; command line length limits on basically every OS would prevent the array from occupying more than a few dozen KB even if the user intentionally tried to break things), but avoiding *anything* from C99 or later is tying one hand behind your back for no reason. Especially since avoiding C11 means tons of modern programming tools (threading, atomics) can't be used in a portable manner without third party libraries.

Answer (score 4):

You need to `NUL` terminate your C-style strings, and that includes allocating enough memory to hold the `NUL`.

Your array is a byte short (must be `char command[strlen(argv[1])+4+1];` to leave space for `NUL`), and you should probably just use something like `sprintf` to fill it in, e.g.:

```
 sprintf(command, "vim %s", argv[1]);`
```

That's simpler than manual loops, and it also fills in the `NUL` for you.

The garbage you see is caused by the search for the `NUL` byte (which terminates the string) wandering off into unrelated (and undefined for that matter) memory that happens to occur after the buffer.

Comment: Humm, it was really what I needed to know, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're running into problems is that you aren't terminating your `command` string with `NULL`.  But you really want to use `sprintf` (or even better to use `snprintf`) for something like this. It works similarly to `printf` but outputs to memory instead of `stdout` and handles the terminating `NULL` for you. E.g:

```
char cmd[80];

snprintf(cmd, 80, "vim %s", argv[1])
system(cmd);
```

As @VTT points out, this simplified code assumes that the value in `argv[1]` will be less than 75 characters (80 minus 4 for "vim " minus 1 for the NULL character). One safer option would be to verify this assumption first and throw an error if it isn't the case. To be more flexible you could dynamically allocate the `cmd` buffer:

```
char *cmd = "vim ";
char *buf = malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + strlen(cmd) + 1);

sprintf(buf, "%s%s", cmd, argv[1]);
system(buf);
free(buf);
```

Of course you should also check to be sure argc > 1.

Comment: @felipX This is actually wrong because the result of `snprintf` must be inspected to determine whether supplied buffer was sufficient.

Comment: @VTT Do you mean if the cmd buffer is of sufficient size to hold `argv[1]`?

Comment: Yes. Allocating string buffers on stack is only acceptable if stored string length is limited by some convention and recursion is limited by some convention as well.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I was taking a short cut. I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

I know that there are already good answers here, but I'd like to expand them a little bit.

I often see this kind of code

```
system("vim %s",argv[1]); //Error:
```

and beginners often wonder, why that is not working.

The reason for that is that `"%s", some_string` is **not** a feature of the C
language, the sequence of characters `%s` has no special meaning, in fact it is
as meaningful as the sequence `mickey mouse`.

The reason why that works with `printf` (and the other members of the
`printf`-family) is because `printf` **was designed** to replace sequences like
`%s` with a value passed as an argument. It's `printf` which make `%s` special,
not the C language.

As you may have noticed, doing `"hallo" + " world"` doesn't do string
concatenation. C doesn't have a native string type that behaves like C++'s
`std::string` or Python's `String`. In C a string is just a sequence of
characters that happen to have a byte with value of 0 at the end (also called
the `'\0'`-terminating byte).

That's why you pass to `printf` a format as the first argument. It tells
`printf` that it should print character by character unless it finds a `%`,
which tells `printf` that the next character(s)<sup>1</sup> is/are special and
must substitute them with the value passed as subsequent arguments to `printf`.

The `%x` are called conversion specifiers and the [documentation of `printf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)
will list all of them and how to use them.

Other functions like the `scanf` family use a similar strategy, but that doesn't
mean that all functions in C that expect strings, will work the same way. In
fact the vast majority of C functions that expect strings, do not work in that
way.

> *man system*
>
> ```
> #include <stdlib.h>
>
> int system(const char *command);
> ```

Here you see that `system` is a function that expects **one** argument only.
That's why your compiler complains with a line like this: `system("vim %s",argv[1]);`.
That's where functions like `sprintf` or `snprintf` come in handy.

---

<sup>1</sup>If you take a look at the `printf` documentation you will see that
the conversion specifier together with length modifiers can be longer than 1
character.

Comment: Oh dude, thanks for this deep explanation, you really made things more clearer. Thank's for your time !

Comment: @felipX that's ok, but the comment system in Stack Overflow should be used to add comments that enhance the question/answer. If you really want to thank somebody, then do it by upvoting/accepting the questions/answers. Note that I'm not telling you to upvote mine, it's just a general recommendation for the future, it's the way we say thank you to the people that help us.